# FTP, permissions: I cannot see permissions but I can change them

Tags: permissions, ftp

I'm browsing a server with my ftp client. When I try to get the information about a folder, I cannot see the permissions (all `rwx` check boxes are unchecked).

If i try to check one of it, the operation is successful (I don't get any error), but then when I come back it is again unchecked.

What does it mean? I don't have privileges to read permissions but I can change them?

Comment: What FTP client are you using?

Comment: Cyberduck on mac. It always worked so far (on 5 6 different servers).

Comment: What kind of server?  The rwx permissions shown by the client are *nix and may not map to the file system of the server.

Comment: It is an IIS Server... I dunno how to provide you more information. What are *nix permissions ? So what should I do to solve it ?

Comment: *nix is Unix/Linux.  There may be a setting on your client to tell it it's connecting to a Windows server.  This should allow it to correctly display/set the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible cause:

In FTP, there is no standard format for directory listings; everything is sent as human-readable text, and GUI FTP clients must try to detect the output format.

Try to either enable the logging function of your FTP client, or use the command-line `ftp`, to see what is actually received from server. Maybe the server doesn't even use permissions? Maybe it uses some strange directory list format?

Comment: ok, I've loged in with the terminal: 220 Microsoft FTP Service

Comment: @Patrick: I actually wanted you to check the actual directory listing... But it doesn't matter now. **"Microsoft FTP service"** already tells us that **it's a Windows system**. And Windows systems **do not have** Unix-style `rwx` permissions. (There _are_ security ACLs in Windows, but they cannot be changed over FTP.)

Comment: Remote system type is Windows_NT. Tell me what other information you need, and how can I get them, and I will write down. thanks

Comment: So what does that mean ? I cannot change permissions through ftp, but I need ssh access ? Is that the only way ?

Comment: @Patrick: Windows systems use a very different way of setting permissions. **There is no `rwx` or `chmod`.** Those are Unix(/Linux/BSD) things. Forget them. (There is no SSH either.)

Comment: ok, do you know how can I change them in Microsoft environment ?

Comment: @Patrick: either `icacls` or the "Security" tab of the file properties box (in Explorer).

Comment: ok, what's a good solution from terminal ?

Comment: @Patrick: [`icacls`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls), like I already said. (Older Windows versions have `cacls`, which is much less capable.)